# Blazor, select an item in for loop of components and deselect the others

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor Webassembly version 5:

I have a `for` loop which iterates over data items to show them and a user should be able to select the items by clicking. What is the best way to achieve that?
I want to select the selected `PersonItem` but deselect the other components. The problem is with deselecting the others.

**PersonItem.Razor:**

```
@if (Person!= null)
{
    <div @onclick="InvokeOnClick" style="@GetStyle()">@Person.Name</div>
}
@code {


    [Parameter] public PersonPerson { get; set; } = null;
    [Parameter] public bool IsSelected { get; set; }=false;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Person> OnClick { get; set; }
    private string GetStyle() => IsSelected ? "cursor:default;color:blue" : "cursor:pointer";

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    private async Task InvokeOnClick()
    {
      IsSelected = true;
      await OnClick.InvokeAsync(Person);
    }
}
```

**MyPage.razor :**

```
@inject IPersonRepo personRepo;



@if (PersonList !)
{
    foreach (var person in PersonList)
    {
        <PersonItem Person="@person"></PersonItem>
    }
}
else
{
    <div>Not Yet!</div>
}


@code {
    public List<Person>? PersonList { get; set; } = null;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetAllPersons(null);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }


    public async Task GetAllPersons(EventArgs e)
    {
        PersonList = await personRepo.GetAllPersons();
    }
}
```

Comment: In short, you want to implement Radio Button style behavior?

Comment: So, just one person can be selected in one moment? Is that the trouble?

Comment: @CaiusJard that could be true.

Comment: @Alamakanambra yes a person is selected but I want other persons to be unselected. Only one person should be selected at a time

Comment: If you take a look at frameworks that provide these (source code for Blazorise, MudBlazor etc) kind of buttons, they normally exist within another container that provides the aggregation/knowledge of other buttons within the same group (so you can have multiple groups per page) and it's effectively the container's job to deselect the others. That said, if you're wiring it up so that each button binds to the same data store variable and sets its own distinct e.g. enum value, then it merely hast to draw itself ticked only if the backing store variable value is equal to the value it sets.

Comment: @CaiusJard I can't believe an easy task like this is impossible in Blazor !!

Comment: [It's not impossible](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/radio/), you just haven't programmed it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have most of the ingredients.
The requirement is fulfilled when you use OnCLick and IsSelected:

```html
foreach (var person in PersonList)
{
    <PersonItem Person="@person" 
           OnClick="SelectPerson" 
           IsSelected="person==selectedPerson" />
}
```

and in @code:

```cs
   
Person selectedPerson = null;

void SelectPerson(Person person)
{
   selectedPerson = person;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Very nice answer !